# ast.literal_eval not working (python string of list to list)

Tags: python, string, list, eval, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to convert the following string of a list back to a list.

```
[('zX7XjZ1Vwai5UbqNDDJ1NQ', 570512, [155])]
```

I have tried both `eval()` and `ast.literal_eval` but for some reason when I print the type of my converted string it is still a string (but with the quotations removed)

I have also tried using `json.loads()`

It seems like no matter how hard I try, I cannot convert this string of a list to a python list!

Comment: `eval` worked for me. what version of python do you have?

Comment: That is not a string of a list but a list with one `tuple`  element that contains `string` and `int` and `list`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, `ast.literal_eval("[('zX7XjZ1Vwai5UbqNDDJ1NQ', 570512, [155])]") == [('zX7XjZ1Vwai5UbqNDDJ1NQ', 570512, [155])]` returns `True`.

Comment: `eval("[('zX7XjZ1Vwai5UbqNDDJ1NQ', 570512, [155])]")` gives `[('zX7XjZ1Vwai5UbqNDDJ1NQ', 570512, [155])]`

Comment: Did you try `type` on result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably have an additional set of quotation marks, not shown in the question, included in the literal you're evaluating:

```
[('zX7XjZ1Vwai5UbqNDDJ1NQ', 570512, [155])]
```

is a list, whereas:

```
"[('zX7XjZ1Vwai5UbqNDDJ1NQ', 570512, [155])]"
```

is a string.

Therefore,

```
ast.literal_eval("[('zX7XjZ1Vwai5UbqNDDJ1NQ', 570512, [155])]")
```

returns a list, whereas:

```
ast.literal_eval('''"[('zX7XjZ1Vwai5UbqNDDJ1NQ', 570512, [155])]"''')
```

returns a string. The nested quotes have become verbose in these examples written as Python source code, but perhaps you've read `"[('zX7XjZ1Vwai5UbqNDDJ1NQ', 570512, [155])]"` from a file.